# The variable is getting overwritten?

Tags: javascript, aura

I have the following code syntax and basically I'm trying to create a new array called dataDraft. For some reason, this code snippet below overrwrites the data, and the dataDraft is basically not correct values. What is the correct way to create a new array and ensure that the "data" variable is not overwritten?

```
let data = component.get('v.myData');

    let dataDraft = data.map(x=>{
        if(x.itemSelected){
            x.status = 'Approved';
        } else {
            x.status = 'Rejected';
        }

        return x;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is in the map function is the same object that's from the index of the Array.

```
let a = [ { message: 'Hello World' } ]
let b = [...a];
b[0].message = 'Goodbye World';
console.log(a[0]); // Goodbye World
```

In order to avoid this behavior, you have to copy the object:

```
let dataDraft = data.map(
  (item) => Object.assign({}, item, { status: item.itemSelected? 'Approved':'Rejected' })
);
```

Here, Object.assign takes the first argument, `{}`, a new object, then adds the properties from `item`, then adds the status property. You can write this out longer if you'd like:

```
let dataDraft = data.map(
  (item) => {
    let itemCopy = Object.assign({}, item);
    if(itemCopy.itemStatus) {
      itemCopy.status = 'Approved';
    } else {
      itemCopy.status = 'Rejected';
    }
    return itemCopy;
  }
);
```

Be careful not to touch `item` in any way, or you'll also modify the original.

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy it before you `map`.

Instead of:

```
let dataDraft = data.map(x=>{
```

use:

```
let dataDraft = [...data].map(x=>{
```

or:

```
let dataDraft = data.slice().map(x=>{
```

Comment: Shallow copy won't help here.